# Finding the smallest solution set, if one exists (two multipliers)

Tags: python, algorithm, set, constraints, set-theory

Note: This is the two-multipliers variation of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909614/finding-the-smallest-solution-set-if-one-exists-n-multipliers)

Given a set `A`, consisting of floats between 0.0 and 1.0, find a smallest set `B` such that for each `a` in `A`, there is either a value where `a == B[x]`, or there is a pair of unique values where `a == B[x] * B[y]`.

For example, given

```
$ A = [0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9]
```

A possible (but probably not smallest) solution for B is

```
$ B = solve(A)
$ print(B)
[0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9]
```

This satisfies the initial problem, because `A[0] == B[0] * B[1]`, `A[1] == B[1]`, etc., which allows us to recreate the original set `A`. The length of `B` is smaller than that of `A`, but I’m guessing there are smaller answers as well.

I assume that the solution space for `B` is large, if not infinite. If a solution exists, how would a smallest set `B` be found?

---

Notes:

- We're not necessarily limited to the items in A. B can consist of any set of values, whether or not they exist in A.
- Since items in A are all 0-1 floats, I'm assuming that B will also be 0-1 floats. Is this the case?
- This may be a constraint satisfaction problem, but I'm not sure how it would be defined?
- Since floating point math is generally problematic, any answer should frame the algorithm around rational numbers.

Comment: The integer counterpart of this problem has a well-developed theory in terms of prime factors, etc. I suggest you look for ways to transform your problem into one involving integers. Then you will also know the computational complexity of the task.

Comment: Working with floats may not give you the result that you expect, unless you are trying to isolate numbers that are powers of two from those that are not.

Comment: Integers are totally doable for my application, if we take the values of `A` as a set of percentages instead, multiplying each by 100. (I actually round down to the nearest .0001 for the values of A, but I could round to .01 if necessary.) What is it about using decimal values that would be unexpected? Just floating point math limits? I'm planning on using Python's Decimal library, which should handle this kind of precision, I believe.

Comment: For example, in IEEE754 double precision, 0.07 * 20 is not equal to 1.4. Working with integers would work.

Comment: @RobertBaron Couldn't this be solved by using a library like Decimal? https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: Not really, there will always be numbers that have no representation as decimal numbers, for example, 1/3. You could however work with rationals.

Comment: your question says "if one exists", a valid solution is always trivially the input isn't it?  or I don't understand your `B[x]` notation

Comment: @SamMason No, if `A = [0.5]`, then the only option for B would be `[0.5]`, which is the same length. In this case, there's no answer. (At least, I'm not aware of a way there could be an answer...) For `B[x]` and `B[y]`, I'm just referring to two different elements in the set B. Since they could be any index, I just used x and y, but they must be different.

Comment: @SamMason You're right that x and y could be the same index, but 2 and 4 aren't possible values for A. You certainly could have a case where `B[x] * B[x] == a`. For example, if you had `A = [0.25, 0.5, 1.0]`, then a valid solution for B is `[0.5, 1.0]`.

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment after rereading your previous comment and seeing "but they must be different" and thought that answered my question.  I don't understand why `[2]` isn't a valid solution for `[2, 4]`, it's just `[B[0], B[0] * B[0]]` which seems to follow your other constraints

Comment: @SamMason The values must be between 0 and 1 in A, and only two values can be multiplied together, not the singleton you have. I'm going to ask another question that uses any number of multipliers.

Comment: @RobertBaron @saucewaffle The `Fraction` class can be used for an exact representation of rationals in Python.

Comment: Thanks @GZ0 - this is exactly what I needed. I’ll note that for later reference

Comment: @GZ0 Yes better than working with floats for this problem.

Comment: I've posted the n-multipliers variation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909614/finding-the-smallest-solution-set-if-one-exists-n-multipliers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the array. For each pair of elements Am, An ∈ A, m < n - calculate their ratio.

Check if the ratio is equal to some element in A, which is not equal to Am nor to An.

Example:

```
A = { 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9 }

(0.125, 0.25): 0.5    <--- bingo
(0.125, 0.5 ): 0.25   <--- bingo
(0.125, 0.75): 0.1(6)
(0.125, 0.9 ): 0.13(8)
(0.25 , 0.5 ): 0.5
(0.25 , 0.75): 0.(3)
(0.25 , 0.9 ): 0.2(7)
(0.5  , 0.75): 0.(6)
(0.5  , 0.9 ): 0.(5) 
(0.75 , 0.9 ): 0.8(3)
```

The numerator (0.125) is redundant (= 0.25 * 0.5) or (= 0.5 * 0.25)

We can do better by introducing new elements:

Another example:

```
A = { 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.2, 0.22, 0.24 }

(0.1 , 0.11): 0.(90)        ***
(0.1 , 0.12): 0.8(3)        +++
(0.1 , 0.2 ): 0.5     <--------
(0.1 , 0.22): 0.(45)
(0.1 , 0.24): 0.41(6)
(0.11, 0,12): 0.91(6)       ~~~
(0.11, 0.2 ): 0.55
(0.11, 0.22): 0.5     <--------
(0.11, 0.24): 0.458(3)
(0.12, 0.2 ): 0.6
(0.12, 0.22): 0.(54)
(0.12, 0.24): 0.5     <--------
(0.2 , 0.22): 0.(90)        ***
(0.2 , 0.24): 0.8(3)        +++
(0.22. 0.24): 0.91(6)       ~~~
```

Any 2 or more pairs (a1,a2), (a3,a4), (... , ...) with a common ratio f can be replaced with { a1, a3, ..., f }.

Hence adding 0.5 to our set makes { 0.1, 0.11, 0.12 } redundant.

```
B = (0.2, 0.22, 0.24, 0.5}
```

We are now (i the general case) left with an optimization problem of selecting which of these elements to remove and which of these factors to add in order to minimize the cardinality of B (which I leave as an exercise to the reader).

Note that there is no need to introduce numbers greater than 1. B can also be represented as { 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 2} but this set has the same cardinality.

Comment: Interesting approach - I do think this may solve it. But how exactly would we find all the factors across the entire set that build the smallest solution? I imagine there would be other combinations of factors that could produce even smaller `B`s?

Comment: Fascinating! I do think this works, but how do we know that this is the smallest cardinality of B we can get? I've not really had time to think through this, but wouldn't it be possible to recursively process B and find more simplifications?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, this will run into issues with floating-point math. May be worth adding an example with rational numbers?

Comment: I chose to represent the numbers in a repeating decimal representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) but you may store them as fractions as well. Both representations are accurate.

Comment: I don't think that you need to process B recursively. If I'm not mistaken, even if you introduce new factors - there is nothing redundant (unless you allow representing numbers as a multiple of three or more elements).

Comment: @saucewaffle, in the first example, I do not undestand how the ratio of `0.125` and `0.5` yields `0.625`. Do you?

Comment: @RobertBaron: my bad. fixed

Comment: @LiorKogan Hmm I think I may have actually not asked the initial question clearly! There's really no limit saying that only two values from B can be used. If you had `A = [0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0]`, then a valid answer for B could be `[0.5, 1.0]`. Meaning, `A == [ B[0]*B[0]*B[0], B[0]*B[0], B[0]*B[1], B[1]*B[1] ]` (I only just realized that this is a valid state, and that it would work for my application!)

Comment: (I added the last comment in the notes to the question for future reference, and updated the top portion to match the fact that the number of elements used to find A[x] doesn't have to be two.)

Comment: @saucewaffle: In this case, it is quite different. The lowest cardinality B may not be the optimal one for the next recursive step. Maybe you should ask another question ;-)

Comment: That's a good point - maybe I'll do that instead, since this does seem to solve this one!

Comment: @saucewaffle Note that `|B| choose 2 + |B| = |A|` or `|B| = 1/2 * (sqrt(8 * |A| + 1) - 1)` is optimal when up to two `b`s are allowed for an `a`. Any single `b` from `B` can participate at most in all pairs that can include it, as well as itself be equal to an `a` from `A`. For example, for `|A| = 6`, the smallest `|B|` would be `3` since `3 choose 2 + 3 = 6`

Comment: @גלעדברקן Very good point - thanks. Since this question is only addressing the case of two multipliers, this would be the upper limit for the problem. Do you know how this would apply if there were no limit on the number of multipliers?

Comment: @saucewaffle if there is no limit on how many `b`s could make up an `a`, it seems to me that the lower limit would be `|B| ≥ log2(|A| + 1)` since we can have at most `2^|B| - 1` non-empty subsets of `B`.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Intresting - thanks! I'll note this on my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909614/finding-the-smallest-solution-set-if-one-exists-n-multipliers

Answer (score 0):

[Google's OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/) provide a nice [CP solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver) which can be used to get solutions to this.  You can encode your problem as a simple set of boolean variables, saying which variables or combinations of variables are valid.

I start by pulling in the relevant part of the library and setting up a few variables:

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

A = [0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9]
# A = [0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.2, 0.22, 0.24]

model = cp_model.CpModel()
```

we can then define a few helper functions for creating variables from our numbers:

```
vars = {}
def get_var(val):
    assert val >= 0 and val <= 1
    if val in vars:
        return vars[val]

    var = model.NewBoolVar(str(val))
    vars[val] = var
    return var

pairs = {}
def get_pair(pair):
    if pair in pairs:
        return pairs[pair]

    a, b = pair
    av = get_var(a)
    bv = get_var(b)

    var = model.NewBoolVar(f'[{a} * {b}]')
    model.AddBoolOr([av.Not(), bv.Not(), var])
    model.AddImplication(var, av)
    model.AddImplication(var, bv)
    pairs[pair] = var
    return var
```

i.e. `get_var(0.5)` will create a boolean variable (with `Name='0.5'`), while `get_pair(0.5, 0.8)` will create a variable and set constraints so that it's only true when 0.5 and 0.8 are also true.  there's a useful document on encoding [boolean logic in ortools](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/boolean_logic.md)

then we can go through `A` figuring out what combinations are valid and adding them as constraints to the solver:

```
for i, a in enumerate(A):
    opts = {(a,)}
    for a2 in A[i+1:]:
        assert a < a2
        m = a / a2
        if m == a2:
            opts.add((m,))
        elif m < a2:
            opts.add((m, a2))
        else:
            opts.add((a2, m))

    alts = []
    for opt in opts:
        if len(opt) == 1:
            alts.append(get_var(*opt))
        else:
            alts.append(get_pair(opt))

    model.AddBoolOr(alts)
```

next we need a way of saying that we prefer variables to be false rather than true.  the minimal version of this is:

```
model.Minimize(sum(vars.values()))
```

but we get much nicer results if we complicate this a bit and put a preference on values that were in `A`:

```
costsum = 0
for val, var in vars.items():
    cost = 1000 if val in A else 1001
    costsum += var * cost
model.Minimize(costsum)
```

finally, we can run our solver and print out a solution:

```
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
print(solver.StatusName(status))

if status in {cp_model.FEASIBLE, cp_model.OPTIMAL}:
    B = [val for val, var in vars.items() if solver.Value(var)]
    print(sorted(B))
```

this gives me back the expected sets of:
`[0.125, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9]` and `[0.2, 0.22, 0.24, 0.5]`
 for the two examples at the top

you could also encode the fact that you only consider solutions valid if `|B| < |A|` in the solver, but I'd be tempted to do that outside